# What determines the alignment of an object levitating in a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, levitation

Can you explain why sometimes (more often) a levitating object is not horizontal

[image][image]

and sometimes it is perfectly horizontal?

[image]

Comment: Um...because some of these are better balanced than others?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, it seems highly unlikely that a flange can have unbalanced mass distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACuriousMind says that  balance enters into it, but think about it a bit more.

What can affect its horizontal position?

1. Its own variations in its mass  distribution.
2. Is the field holding it up constant across the bottom surface?
3. Is there anything in the space between the two objects (probably not, but you could not rule this out, especially if the levitating object was light enough or had a shape (such as an airfoil ) that lifted one edge of it, if there was was say, a breeze from the side.
4. If you have only seen videos of it occuring, can you be sure they were filmed properly.

So if is not horizontal, it could due to any or all of these factors

When the levitation effect starts, it will be virtually impossible to archive an immediately constant upward field and this will cause the top object to twist in the horizontal plane.  It takes time for this rocking to be dampened down, so maybe you have seen it both just when it was starting to levitate and later when it had settled down in a much more constant magnetic field.

Comment: In this [video](http://hight3ch.com/amazing-magnetic-levitation-device/) you can see how the flange is put onto the magnetic platform. Does it mean something?

Answer (score 0):

If the magnetic field was perfectly linear, then a floating object would be free to spin. However, the strength of the field increases faster the further you go down. As a result, a vertically-aligned object will be repelled more than a horizontally-aligned object with the same center of gravity. Pushing it up increases the potential energy. Reorienting it does not. As a result, it tends to just reorient to a horizontal position.

This is similar to why floating objects end up being oriented horizontally.